# Why my binary image dilation function doesn't  work properly?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I'm having a kind of trouble since I'm new the concept Image Analysis and the tool Matlab.
What I have in my mind does not work well as lines of codes.

I'm trying to dilation function for binary images. It has to widen the given binary images.

This is my main page:

```
I = imread('logo_XXXX.png');
binaryImage = im2bw(I, 0.4);
s = ones(3,3,'int8');
i = dilate(binaryImage,s);
figure, imshow(i);
```

This is dilate.m function:

```
function [i] = dilate(I,s)
[Irows,Icols] = size(I);
i=I;
Itemp = I;
for row=1:Irows
    for col=1:Icols
        x = intersectAt(Itemp,s,row,col);
        if x == 1
            i(row,col)=1;
        else
            i(row,col)=0;
        end
    end
end
```

And this is istersectAt.m function:

```
function [i] = intersectAt(I,s,row,col)
[Srows,Scols] = size(s);
[Irows,Icols] = size(I);
i=0;
rowx = row - int8(Srows/2);
colx = col - int8(Scols/2);

for r=1:Srows
    for c=1:Scols
        if rowx+r <= 0 || rowx+r > Irows || colx+c <= 0 || colx+c > Icols
            continue;
        elseif I(rowx+r,colx+c) == 1 && s(r,c)==1
            i = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

These codes must be widen this image:

[image]

however, in some point it doesn't work properly s.t:

[image]

If you help me fix my code I would be appriciated. If you want to know about dilation you can follow this url: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f18-12508.html

Matlab has this function in its library but i need to implement my own function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give a hint then. Ask yourself what `int8()` exactly does for a number larger then 127. Incidentally the column index number after which your algorithm start behaving weird.

Edit to clarify

If you subtract a `int8` type number from another one, a `double` in this case, Matlab will automatically cast to `int8`. For example:

```
test = double(140) - int8(3)
```

Gives a 127.

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid loops as much as possible in matlab.

If you need to write your own function just do:

```
s=ones(3);
i=(conv2(double(binaryImage),s,'same')>0)
```

From your example:

[image]

I can obtain:

[image]

Comment: what actually this statement do? can you give a brief information? I would be glad.

Comment: It does a convolution with your filter `s`. And then take all the values above zero.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I really like your answer, it works perfect. However, my instructor would not accept this answer for my assignment. I need to write my code as low level as possible.

Comment: In that case, my policy is to not answer to homework's question. you should do it on your own if you want to learn. Obviously your code works for the left half of the image. So you should just have an indexing problem.

Comment: I'm looking for an indexing problem for three hours but i couldn't find any. Then, I thought there may be mistakes that is relevant to Matlab because I've just started to work on Matlab today :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume imdilate is implemented with conv2, but your code would be more readable if you used this:

```
b = imdilate(bwImage,ones(3));
```

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Yes, I've posted the exact same answer before, but I've deleted it because he says at the end of his question: `Matlab has this function in its library but i need to implement my own function.`